# how to select All checkbox based group in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, checkbox

I did initial state for select single checkbox .Here is my intial state

```
     this.state = {
          fruites: [
            { id: 1 , value: "banana", isChecked: false },
            { id: 2, value: "apple", isChecked: false },
            { id: 3,value: "mango", isChecked: false },
            { id: 4, value: "grap", isChecked: false }
          ]
        };
      }
```

Method:  I just this for selected all checkbox

```
      handleAllChecked = id => event => {
        let fruites = this.state.fruites;
        fruites.forEach(fruite => {
          data.filter(item => 
              fruite.isChecked = event.target.checked;

          });
        });
        this.setState({ fruites: fruites });
      };
```

I just this method for individual checkbox .

```
      handleCheckChieldElement = event => {
        let fruites = this.state.fruites;
        fruites.forEach(fruite => {
          if (fruite.value === event.target.value)
            fruite.isChecked = event.target.checked;
        });
        this.setState({ fruites: fruites });
      };
```

Render:Here is my UI, I want to select All checkbox based on group . For example , I have got two group of value - such as Group , Topgroup. The problem is that , When I click on the group , it will select All checkbox including Topgroup and also I click banana , it will select all banana , I don't want to get all banana when click on one item. I don't to want to get topgroup checkbox when I select on the group.

```
            {[{ id: 1, name: "group" }, { id: 2, name: "topGropup" }].map(item => (
              <div>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={this.handleAllChecked(item.id)}
                  value="checkedall"
                />{" "}
                {item.name}
                <ul>
                  {this.state.fruites.map((fruite, index) => {
                    return (
                      <CheckBox
                        key={index}
                        handleCheckChieldElement={this.handleCheckChieldElement}
                        {...fruite}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

How can I resolve this problem . Here is my codesanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-checkbox-or6ko

Answer (score 1):

Here, I edited your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-checkbox-bbuky

Basically you have 8 checkboxes, even though its 4 items displayed, duplicated for each group.

I added the 4 missing items in your state, but you'd actually want some kind of factory function that lets you create your state given the groups you have.

I had to edit some of your values since you were relying on stuff that now is not unique anymore, like `value` and use the group's `id` for example to create a unique identifier `groupId-itemId`.

Comment: I want to select whole checkbox . what i have to do ? can you edit

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Forexample, We have a got group based checkbox but I want to give another options.user can select ALL Checkbox in the list of data

Comment: Oh, then you have to do implement the same thing as I did for `handleAllChecked()`, without the `.filter()` part, since you want them all.

Answer (score 1):

### Memory pointer to the same list

The groups in the app have the same pointer to memory list of fruits.

because of that the updates will affect on both groups.

See how I fixed it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-checkbox-r29d1

I found some things in the app that can be improve so I improve them for example:

`label` to `input` checkbox to be able to click also on the text

I am here if you have any problem, I suggest you to learn Hooks.

Comment: Hi there  can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831082/how-to-filtering-between-array-of-sub-arrays-and-array-of-sub-arrays-in-javascri