# how to filtering javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have got two arrays . I am filtering based groupKey with PubSidebar.

```js
let groupKey = ['oaDeal', 'Journals', 'Deposit'] 
   // This array of object will be filtering with groupKey
const PubSidebar = [
  {
    value: 'Dashboard',
    role: 'public',
  },
  {
    value: 'oaDeal',
    role: 'private',
    content: [
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'oaDeal',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 'Journals',
    role: 'public',
    content: [
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Journals',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Token',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'policy',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Deposit',
      },
      { role: 'public', value: 'test' },
    ],
  },
]
// Here is my trying code. I am filtering PubSidebar
const res = PubSidebar.filter(x => {
  // when it's main outerloop role public or private and groupKey matched
  if (
    x.role === 'public' ||
    (x.role === 'private' && groupKey.includes(x.value))
  ) {
    // then if inner-array exist then inner array filtering
    if (x.content) {
      // inside content assign condition public or private and groupKey
      let tempX = x.content.filter(
        y =>
          y.role === 'public' ||
          (y.role === 'private' && groupKey.includes(y.value)) ||
          x.value === y.value
      )
      x.content = tempX
      console.log(tempX)
      return x
    } else {
      // Other wise give me a single object public
      console.log(x)
      return x
    }
  }



})
```

I am facing problem to pass objects inside content array if parents value: Journals or Deposits or any value or role:pubic. I have to pass value inside content array based on `groupKey`.

If Journals and Deposits is existed , then adding Journals and Deposit data inside content array, including with public data . (three Objects)

If Journals is existed , then adding Journals data inside content array including with public data(two Objects) 
If Deposits is existed , then adding Deposits data inside content array including with public data(two Objects)

if GroupKey journals is matched with content object in pubsidebar then two objects , we will get

```
{
    value: 'Journals',
    role: 'public',
    content: [
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Journals',
      },
      { role: 'public', value: 'test' },
    ],
  }
```

if GroupKey Deposits is matched with content object in pubsidebar then two objects

```
{
    value: 'Deposit',
    role: 'public',
    content: [
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Deposit',
      },
      { role: 'public', value: 'test' },
    ],
  }
```

if GroupKey Journals and Deposits is matched with content object in pubsidebar then three objects ,

```
    {
        value: 'Deposit' || "Journals",
        role: 'public',
        content: [
{
            role: 'private',
            value: 'Journals',
          },
          {
            role: 'private',
            value: 'Deposit',
          },
          { role: 'public', value: 'test' },
        ],
      }
```

Comment: Expected output ???

Comment: just edit , can you see

Comment: where is the difference?

Comment: I just want to pass Object inside content based groupKey . For example Deposits and Journals is matched with PubSidebar content Journals and Deposits then we got three objects including public one . if Deposits doesn't matched then deposit will be removed from pubsidebar

Comment: if GroupKey journals is matched with  content object in pubsidebar then two objects , we got  {value:"journals",role:"private} and   { role: 'public', value: 'test' },

Comment: if GroupKey Deposits is matched with content object in pubsidebar then two objects , we got {value:"Deposits",role:"private} and { role: 'public', value: 'test' },

Comment: if GroupKey Journals and Deposits is matched with content object in pubsidebar then three objects , we got {value:"journals",role:"private} , {value:"Deposits",role:"private} and { role: 'public', value: 'test' },

Comment: @xdeepakv can you understand right now?

Comment: I hope you can understand @NinaScholz

Comment: Show the expected output in json... no wording :(

Comment: input and output looks same here..what u are expecting write it

Comment: I just edited my question can you see now

Comment: @xdeepakv can you understand

Comment: @xdeepakv can you understand

Comment: please select an example of data where some items get filtered out an som have to stay and do the same for nested items.

Comment: I am adding an example in my code

Comment: These objects will be removed from content because there are n Token and policy in GroupKey  {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Token',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'policy',
      },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to filter PubSidebar. Keeping values if they have a role of public or a value of whats included in the groupKey. If so this would be your function:

```
PubSidebar.filter(x => (x.role === 'public' || groupKey.includes(x.value));
```

If you want to run that on content as well we could pull it apart:

```
const filterByGroup = (x) => (x.role === 'public' || groupKey.includes(x.value));

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < PubSidebar.length; i++) {
  const item = PubSidebar[i];

  if (filterByGroup(item)) {
    if (item.content) {
      item.content = item.content.filter(filterByGroup);
    }
    result = [ ...result, item ];
  }
}
```

Snippet:

```js
let groupKey = ['oaDeal', 'Journals', 'Deposit']
const PubSidebar = [{
    value: 'Dashboard',
    role: 'public',
  },
  {
    value: 'oaDeal',
    role: 'private',
    content: [{
      role: 'private',
      value: 'oaDeal',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    value: 'Journals',
    role: 'public',
    content: [{
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Journals',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Token',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'policy',
      },
      {
        role: 'private',
        value: 'Deposit',
      },
      {
        role: 'public',
        value: 'test'
      },
    ],
  },
]

const filterByGroup = (x) => (x.role === 'public' || groupKey.includes(x.value));

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < PubSidebar.length; i++) {
  const item = PubSidebar[i];

  if (filterByGroup(item)) {
    if (item.content) {
      item.content = item.content.filter(filterByGroup);
    }
    result = [...result, item];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @sujon sure - added

Answer (score 2):

You could take a filtering for any depth and reassemble the objects for the result.

```js
const
    filter = ({ content = [], ...o }) => {
        content = content.flatMap(filter);
        if (o.role !== 'public' && !groupKey.includes(o.value)) return [];
        return content.length ? { ...o, content } : o;
    },
    groupKey = ['oaDeal', 'Journals', 'Deposit'],
    pubSidebar = [{ value: 'Dashboard', role: 'public' }, { value: 'oaDeal', role: 'private', content: [{ role: 'private', value: 'oaDeal' }] }, { value: 'Journals', role: 'public', content: [{ role: 'private', value: 'Journals' }, { role: 'private', value: 'Token' }, { role: 'private', value: 'policy' }, { role: 'private', value: 'Deposit' }, { role: 'public', value: 'test' }] }],
    result = pubSidebar.flatMap(filter);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

apply `filter` on array items and on content of each item.

```js
const update = (data, keys) => {
  const publicOrGroup = ({ role, value }) =>
    role === "public" || keys.includes(value);

  return data.filter(publicOrGroup).map(({ content = [], ...item }) => ({
    ...item,
    content: content.filter(publicOrGroup)
  }));
};

const groupKey = ["oaDeal", "Journals", "Deposit"];
const PubSidebar = [
  {
    value: "Dashboard",
    role: "public"
  },
  {
    value: "oaDeal",
    role: "private",
    content: [
      {
        role: "private",
        value: "oaDeal"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "Journals",
    role: "public",
    content: [
      {
        role: "private",
        value: "Journals"
      },
      {
        role: "private",
        value: "Token"
      },
      {
        role: "private",
        value: "policy"
      },
      {
        role: "private",
        value: "Deposit"
      },
      {
        role: "public",
        value: "test"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(update(PubSidebar, groupKey));
```